# ES6 arrow syntax returns function not value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a react component of subcomponents with:

```
const Miniviews = ({reducedArry}) => {
  Object.keys(reducedArry).map((applicationId) => {
    return (
      <div id={applicationId}>
        {reducedArry[applicationId].map(miniview => (
          <Miniview
            key={miniview.id}
            id={miniview.id}
            title={miniview.name}
            handleOpenButton={this.handleMiniviewOpenView}
            />)
        )}
      </div>
    )
  })
};
console.log(Miniviews);
```

and displaying it in the render method with

```
{ this.state.showViews      && <Miniviews reducedArry={reducedArry} /> }
```

however, the value of Miniviews is actually not the returned objects from the function, but the object itself. The console.log outputs:

```
function Miniviews(_ref) {
        var reducedArry = _ref.reducedArry;

        Object.keys(reducedArry).map(function (applicationId) {
          return _react2.default.createElement(
           …
```

How can I make it return what I expect, which is:

```
<div id="1">
<Miniview />
<Miniview />
</div>
<div id="2">
<Miniview / >
</div>
```

Comment: For questions like this, it's really useful to put a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). That way, people helping you can see the problem actually happen, and can show you the fix working in their answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. *"the value of Miniviews is actually not the returned objects from the function"* That's right, you're defining `Miniviews` as a function (an arrow function), and not calling it. To call it, you'd do `Miniviews(relevantArgumentHere)` after.
2. You're using a *verbose* arrow function, which means you need to use an explicit `return`. If you use a *concise* arrow function (without `{` after `=>`), the return is implicit.

Here's an example of a concise arrow function:

```
const f = () => "foo";
```

and the equivalent verbose:

```
const f = () => { return "foo"; };
```

So either concise:

```
const Miniviews = ({reducedArry}) => // Note no { here
  Object.keys(reducedArry).map((applicationId) => {
    return (
      <div id={applicationId}>
        {reducedArry[applicationId].map(miniview => (
          <Miniview
            key={miniview.id}
            id={miniview.id}
            title={miniview.name}
            handleOpenButton={this.handleMiniviewOpenView}
            />)
        )}
      </div>
    )
  })
; // And no } before the ; here
console.log(Miniviews(someArgumentHere));
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----- calling the function
```

or verbose with `return`:

```
const Miniviews = ({reducedArry}) => {
  return Object.keys(reducedArry).map((applicationId) => {
// ^^-- note this return
    return (
      <div id={applicationId}>
        {reducedArry[applicationId].map(miniview => (
          <Miniview
            key={miniview.id}
            id={miniview.id}
            title={miniview.name}
            handleOpenButton={this.handleMiniviewOpenView}
            />)
          )}
      </div>
    )
  })
};
console.log(Miniviews(someArgumentHere));
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----- calling the function
```

Comment: It's also the case that the function isn't being called, right?

Comment: @Pointy: Yeah, I just added #1 above, I missed the comment in the question about the result of the `console.log` initially.

Comment: Using the return gives me a: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: @Wayneio: It shouldn't if you put the `return` where it is above. (Side note: I removed the wrong `}` in the concise form -- fixed now -- but if you added the return and stayed with the verbose form that wouldn't be the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

You never return anything from `Miniviews` function.

Try this:

```
const Miniviews = ({reducedArry}) => {
 return Object.keys(reducedArry).map((applicationId) => {
   return (
     <div id={applicationId}>
       {reducedArry[applicationId].map(miniview => (
         <Miniview
           key={miniview.id}
           id={miniview.id}
           title={miniview.name}
           handleOpenButton={this.handleMiniviewOpenView}
           />)
         )}
       </div>
     )
   })
 };
```

Comment: The function (`Miniviews`) isn't called, so the value of `Miniviews` is still just a function reference.